# is there a way to bring the output of a js file into the script of an html file?I

Tags: node.js, client

Im trying to load a new page in a local browser when a certain condition is checked but im wondered, can the output of a function in a nodejs be brought into the client side/html file?

Comment: What output? You need to be show us more of what you're trying to do because as it is now this question is very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are many ways to do it, [ExpressJS](https://expressjs.com/) is a very common way of passing variables through. I have also used [SocketIO](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client) and personally prefer it over Express.